# Is there a default cookie or way of identifying guests, Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I want to write a module that would work similarly to the guest checkout, I need to know the identity of guests.

Preferably I want to use the default way of doing this / accessing the value already there if that exists?

Comment: Surely if you knew their identity, they would not be a guest?

Comment: I mean a guest visitor cookie?

Comment: A guest is by definition a person that isn't logged in as a customer, so on the server side you could just check if they are logged in `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()`.

Comment: That isn't what I'm asking. I want to maintain persistence with a user who isn't logged in.